# How to remove color stripes in list view in Finder (Mountain Lion)?

Tags: macos, finder

The title says it all.
I would like to have clean white background in finder (in list view).
I don't want these pale blue stipes (alternating background color).

I'm pretty sure this is possible, since it was possible before (I managed to remove them back then in Snow Leopard). However, when I narrow the Google search to one year, nothing comes up.

The only tweak I managed to find is this:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071101062430328

I tried it, but it didn't change anything. It's for 10.5.

EDIT: I added a screenshot. Above is a Finder windows **with** stripes, below is a Path Finder window **without** stripes. I'm looking for a way to have the Finder without stripes too, just a clean white background.

[image: Above: Finder with stripes. Below: Path Finder without stripes.]

Comment: Are you sure you are on Mountain Lion? (I think it's impossible)

Comment: My current OS is 10.8.5. I installed Mavericks on a separate USB drive just to play a little with it, but I'll wait for initial patches before I put in on the primary drive.

Comment: So the strippes are in Mountain Lion?

Comment: Correct. And I want to remove them. I want the list view to have a clean white background. This is very easy to set in Path Finder, it's one checkbox. However, in Finder, not even Tinker Tools don't seem to give that option.

Comment: I just added a screenshot.